# Get tables and columns from database - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Database `abc` and it contains 2 tables `table1` and `table2`.

I would like to have something like this:

**table1**

```
column1 int
column2 nvarchar(50)
```

**table2**

```
column1 int
column2 money
column3 bit
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` schema and the objects within it like

```
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

which has all of that metadata you need to produce the output you want.

Comment: SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME as [Column], ISNULL(DATA_TYPE + '(' + cast(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH as nvarchar(10)) +')', DATA_TYPE) as [Data type]
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS

Answer (score 2):

Try use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_CATALOG='My_Database_Name_Here'
```

or

```
select TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_CATALOG='My_Database_Name_Here'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just write a query something like this:

```
USE abc --change this to whatever database you have your tables in

SELECT Table_Name
    ,Column_Name
    ,DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('table1','table2')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME as [Column], 
    ISNULL(DATA_TYPE + '(' + cast(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH as nvarchar(10)) +')', DATA_TYPE) as [Data type] 
FROM 
    information_schema.COLUMNS
```